# Is there a way to know App Reviews from users in real time?

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect

I don't know why Apple can't provide a real-time system and tools to manage these processes better but is there a way to know about app reviews from users in real-time? I wish there is a way for Downloads and In-App Purchases as well.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is currently not possible. You can view reviews of your app on the App Store once the submission has been confirmed, but this is not real time. Download/IAP statistics are only updated when Apple updates the reports.